# How to inject bean of type Supplier?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have code as follows

```
public class A {
@Inject
private Supplier<Set<String>> set;
.
.
}
```

I am writing test cases for this class, where my Unit test looks like :

```
@Test(groups = "MyApp.unit")
public class ATest extends someOtherClass {

    @Inject
    private A a;
```

& my unit config looks like

```
@Configuration
@Import({someClass.class})
public class UnitTestConfig {
...
 @Bean
    public Supplier<Set<String>> set() {
        Supplier<Set<String>> items = () -> Sets.newHashSet("100");
        return items;
    }

@Bean
    public A a() {
        return new A();
    }


}
```

I am unable to inject Supplier bean into my class A. Had put debug points and tried testing, it enters the bean function but Supplier class doesnt get created. It gives the message "Class has no fields"

All other beans seem fine. Does anyone have any insights on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're already using the `@Configuration` to configure the bean, why won't you use constructor injection?

I suggest you to rewrite the `A` class as follows:

```
public class A {
    private final Supplier<Set<String>> sup;

    public A(Supplier<Set<String>> sup) {
        this.sup = sup;
    }
}
```

Now you can use one of the following options:

```
@Configuration
public class SampleConfig {
    @Bean
    public Supplier<Set<String>> set () {
        return () -> Set.of("a","b", "c");
    }

    @Bean
    public A a (Supplier<Set<String>> sup) {
        return new A(sup);
    }
}
```

Or another way:

```
@Configuration
public class SampleConfig {
    @Bean
    public Supplier<Set<String>> set () {
        return () -> Set.of("a","b", "c");
    }

    @Bean
    public A a () {
        return new A(set());
    }  
}
```

In the second option I call `set()` as if its a regular method. Spring handles classes annotated with `@Configuration`, so its a "special" call used for injection.
Since a supplier is a singleton, multiple calls to this `set` method (say, from different beans) will return the same instance of the Supplier.

The first method is more flexible though, because it allows to keep the definition of the supplier and class A in different configuration files, the second way assumes that they're both defined in the same `@Configuration`.

**Update (based on Op's Comments)**

With field injection it will work just the same:

```
public class A {

    @Autowired
    private Supplier<Set<String>> sup;

    public Set<String> getSet() {
        return this.sup.get();
    }

}
```

```
@Configuration
public class SampleConfig {
    @Bean
    public Supplier<Set<String>> set () {
        return () -> Set.of("a","b", "c");
    }

    @Bean
    public A a () {
        return new A();
    }

    // this is called right before the application gets started (after all the injections are done - this is just for the sake of illustration)
    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void onReady(ApplicationReadyEvent evt) {
        A a = evt.getApplicationContext().getBean(A.class);
        System.out.println(a.getSet()); // this will return your set
    }
}
```

Comment: the application is written without using constructor injection and uses Inject annotation for injecting beans. It seems to work fine for all the other beans except Supplier.. I am trying to make it work w the same in keeping w the application structure

Comment: maybe it could be because its a lambda, when checking the bean creation in debug, it shows ```set = {UnitTestConfig$lambda@3808}``` 
& on expanding "Class has no fields"

Comment: With autowiring (`@Autowired`, `@Inject` whatever) it works just the same. Supplier indeed doesn't have fields, but if you'll call a "get" on it, you'll see your set. I've updated the answer showing the use case for field injection

Comment: didnt get your soln, you are saying Supplier should get injected? In my case it doesnt. And unless it gets injected we cant call get() right ?

Comment: I'm saying (I've verified that code snippet also) that supplier gets injected as usual - nothing special here. Till it gets injected, class A's field 'sup' is null, and can't do anything with it. The actual injection in the case of field injection happens __after__ the object gets created (after constructor) Technically spring has a bean post processor for that. So you can't do anything with this field in constructor, however (in the code that happens after the app starts) you can access the field. Since its a supplier, you can only 'get' on it and get a result, that's what you can do...